# Debugging admin_data in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to rails and ruby and was able to stitch together my first app and launch it on heroku. All is well, and now I'm trying to solve the problem of how to manage my data. I found the plugin called "admin_data" and it seemed to be the right choice.

Admin_data works great locally but when I deploy it to heroku I just get the message "We're sorry, but something went wrong. (500)". If I restrict access I get the correct response of "not authorized".

I have no idea what's going wrong, and more importantly, don't know how to look into the cause of the error. Any tips on getting a verbose message from heroku or tuning admin_data are much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

'admin_data' by default only works in a 'development' environment.

You can either set your Heroku app to 'development' environment (http://docs.heroku.com/config-vars) or add your environment to an 'admin_data' config file (config instructions for a Rails 3 app are here: https://github.com/neerajdotname/admin_data/wiki/admin_data-security-configuration-for-a-Rails3-application):

```
AdminData.config do |config|
  config.is_allowed_to_view = lambda {|controller| return true if (Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?) }
  config.is_allowed_to_update = lambda {|controller| return true if (Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?) }
end
```